# Python Django no module named app in eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, migration

I just made first django project in eclipse. I created an app and did 'make migration' so that create tables in admin but got this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jeon hyun joo\workspace\blog\blog\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
django.setup()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
app_config.ready()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 23, in ready
self.module.autodiscover()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "C:\Users\jeon hyun joo\workspace\blog\blog\polls\admin.py", line 2, in <module>
from blog.polls.models import Question, Choice
ImportError: No module named polls.models
Finished "C:\Users\jeon hyun joo\workspace\blog\blog\manage.py makemigrations polls" execution.
```

I registered app in settings.py

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'polls'
    ]
```

and also I have **init.py** file in every packages.
What I did in this project is creating one application and editing models.py and admin.py. I haven't created any other files. What can I do to solve this problem?

I added urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: can u add your url.py file

Comment: @bobmarti I added it. Actually I didn't edit urls.py because I haven't create any templates.

Comment: whisch tutorial which helps you to do first django project in eclipse

Comment: from blog.polls.models import Question, Choice instead of this use from polls.models import Question, Choice

Comment: may be its is the problem of your pythonpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to register your models in Admin page. Try two things,

1. Try to change your import statement, as in,

   ```
   from .models import Question, Choice
   #or
   from polls.models import Question, Choice
   ```
2. Add (explicitly) `blog` as well as `polls` to your `PYTHONPATH`
3. Comment out the code that is causing the migration issue, as in, comment out your import(which will cause you to comment out other lines as well). Just keep on doing that for all the lines which fails your migration.

Comment: for me from .models import Question, Choice worked. thanks!